# How can I declare a template friend function to a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry, this question seems to have been asked many times, but I could not get the other answers to work for my setup. I have the following class and function setup:

```
namespace ddd {
  template <typename T>
  class A {
    ...
  };

  template <typename T, typename U>
  A<T> a_func(const A<U> &a) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to declare a_func as a friend of A, and I want it so that a_func is a friend for all instances of A, no matter which typename is used for T and U (e,g, a_func can access A).

Thanks!

Comment: I read what you wrote, and yet wonder what you mean with *a friend for all instances*... Do you want `a_func<int,double>` to be a friend of `A<std::string:>`? Or do you mean that no matter what the instantiating type `T1` for `A` you want `a_func<T1,U>` (possibly also `a_func<U,T1>`) to be friends of `A<T>`?

Comment: I want a_func<int, double> to be a friend of A<std::string>.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way (which looks like how you had it):

```
template<typename X>
class A {
    template<typename T, typename U>
    friend A<T> a_func(const A<U>& a);
};

template<typename T, typename U>
A<T> a_func(const A<U>& a) {
    // whatever
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/H1ZVF)

Comment: @Max: What errors did you get? This should work (well, after removing `friend` from the definition of the of the template)...